# Laravel Socialite facebook get user phone number

Tags: facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-socialite

I use `laravel socialite` for authentication users on my website. I get basic user data, but I need `user_phone`, because some users signet up for Facebook with a phone number.
Unfortunately in the documentation I have not found a field `phone_number`

This is screenschot based FB doc, ebout email field:

[image]

The question: if the field email is empty, where to look for a number???

Comment: You don’t get a user’s phone number via API.

Answer (score 1):

Phone number is not available using Facebook API check available fields here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I don't agree that this qualifies as a link-only answer that's recommended to be deleted. There's not much from the link to be quoted in the answer. Personally, I would post this as a comment, but I wouldn't recommend deleting the answer either as it specifies that the phone number can't be obtained through the API _(which is an answer on its own)_ and provides a link for reference.

Comment: I totally agree with @AhmedAbdelhameed, there is literally nothing to quote from the reference link. This should be marked as an answer.

Comment: Let's save our energy it's simple question with simple answer and the link are refereeing to the exact information that could help to find more related information @chade_ I will consider referenced meta

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this. Credits goes to @amirhazz, the full thread can be found here : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/socialite-facebook-extra-fields?page=1

```
class FacebookLogin {

    /**
     * Since facebook will give you name, email, gender by default,
     * You'll only need to initialize Facebook scopes after getting permission
     */

    const facebookScope = [
        'user_birthday',
        'user_location',
    ];

    /**
     * Initialize Facebook fields to override
     */
    const facebookFields = [
        'name', // Default
        'email', // Default
        'gender', // Default
        'birthday', // I've given permission
        'location', // I've given permission
    ];

    public function facebookRedirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields(self::facebookFields)->scopes(self::facebookScope)->redirect();
    }

    public function facebookCallback()
    {
        $facebook = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields(self::facebookFields)->user();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18114126)

Comment: Im sorry but I dont get it Mr. Oliver Spryn.